Extensions of $G$-modules parametrized by $H^1$
Let $G$ be a finitely generated group and let $V$, $W$ be one-dimensional representations of $G$ over $\mathbb{F}_q$. (I guess one can think of $V$ and $W$ simply as $G$-modules, which are isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_q$, as $\mathbb{F}_q$ vector spaces)
Up to scalars, equivalences of extensions
\begin{equation}
        0\to W \to E \to V\to 0
\end{equation}
are parametrized by $\operatorname{Ext}^1_G(V,W):=H^1(\operatorname{Hom}(F',W)^{G})$ where $F'\to V$ is a projective resolution of $V$ over $\mathbb{Z}G$ and $(-)^G$ is the invariants functor.

Is it true that $\operatorname{Ext}^1_G(V,W) = H^1(G,V^{\vee}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} W)$, the group cohomology of $G$, with coefficients in $V^{\vee}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} W$?

My reasons to believe it is true are This spectral sequence, and this attempt to prove it here on math.stackexchange.com, where I could not have an answer. The problem in my attempt here was that taking a projective resolution of $\mathbb{Z}$ over $\mathbb{Z}G$, and tensoring it wit $\mathbb{F}_q$ is not necessarily a projective resolution of $V$.
Thank you for any help or references.

If you worked over $\mathbb F_qG$ instead (i.e., took $\mathrm{Ext}^1_{\mathbb F_qG}(V,W)$ and $V^{\vee}\otimes_{\mathbb F_q} W$, this would be true.  But I suspect that it need not be true in your context.

Thank you. In the case where everything is over $\mathbb F_q G$, how should I make sense of the group cohomology $H^1(G,M)$ for some $\mathbb{F}_qG$-module $M$? Should it be defined as $H^1(\operatorname{Hom}(F,M)^{G})$ for some projective resolution $F\to \mathbb{F}_q$ of $\mathbb{F}_q$ over $\mathbb{F}_qG$? Actually in every textbook I see, this is defined over $\mathbb Z G$, so this is really interesting if it works also overs other group rings like $\mathbb{F}_qG$.

You get the same answer if you take a projective resolution of Fq over FqG or Z over ZG.  You can see this by observing that a free ZG-resolution of Z is also a free resolution over Z, so tensoring with Fq over Z and taking homology gives tor(Fq,Z) which vanishes above dimension 0 and so this stays exact and gives a free resolution of Fq over FqG

The correct version of your statement is the following.  Let $K$ be a commutative ring and suppose that $V,W$ are (left) $KG$-modules with $V$ finitely generated projective over $K$.  Then $$\mathrm{Ext}_{KG}^n(V,W)\cong H^n(G,\hom(V,K)\otimes_K W).$$
The proof is like this. If $A,B$ are $KG$-modules, then $\hom_K(A,B)$ is a $KG$-module with $G$ acting by conjugation. Moreover, $$\hom_{KG}(K,\hom_K(A,B))\cong \hom_K(A,B)^G\cong \hom_{KG}(A,B).$$  Take an injective resolution $W\to I_\bullet$ over $KG$.  Then $\hom_{KG}(V,I_\bullet)\cong \hom_K(K,\hom_K(V, I_\bullet))$.  Notice that since $\hom_K(V,-)$ is exact because $V$ is $K$-projective, we have that $\hom_K(V,W)\to \hom_K(V,I_\bullet)$ is a resolution.   It is straightforward to check that if $I$ is an injective $KG$-module, then there is a natural isomorphism $\hom_{KG}(-,\hom_K(V,I))\cong \hom_{KG}(-\otimes_K V,I)$, and hence this functor is exact, as $V$ is $K$-projective and $I$ is injective.  Thus $\hom_K(V,I)$ is injective.  It follows that  $\hom_K(V,W)\to \hom_K(V,I_\bullet)$ is an injective resolution.  Taking cohomology we see that $$\mathrm{Ext}^n_{KG}(V,W)\cong \mathrm{Ext}^n_{KG}(K,\hom_K(V,W))\cong \mathrm{Ext}^n_{KG}(K,\hom(V,K)\otimes_K W)$$ since $V$ is a finitely generated projective $KG$-module.
It remains to observe that if $M$ is a $KG$-module, then $\mathrm{Ext}^n_{KG}(K,M)\cong H^n(G,M)$.  For this, take a free resolution $F_\bullet\to \mathbb Z$ over $\mathbb ZG$.  Notice that $H_n(K\otimes_{\mathbb Z} F_\bullet)\cong \mathrm{Tor}^{\mathbb Z}_n(K,\mathbb Z)$ since each free $\mathbb ZG$-module is a free $\mathbb Z$-module.  We conclude that $H_n(K\otimes_{\mathbb Z}F_\bullet)=0$ for $n\geq 1$ and is $K$ when $n=0$.  Thus $K\otimes_{\mathbb Z}F_\bullet$ is a free resolution of $K$ over $KG$.  Therefore, $$H^n(G,M)\cong H^n(\hom_{\mathbb ZG}(F_\bullet,M))\cong H^n(\hom_{KG}(K\otimes_{\mathbb Z}F_\bullet,M))\cong \mathrm{Ext}^n_{KG}(K,M).$$
One can generalize this argument to show that if $V$ is a finitely generated projective $K$-module and $U,W$ are $KG$-modules, then $\mathrm{Ext}^n_{KG}(U\otimes V,W)\cong \mathrm{Ext}^n(U,\hom_K(V,K)\otimes W)$, where $U=K$ in the previous case.
Of course, if $K$ is a field then any finite dimensional $KG$-module is $K$-projective.

Thank you for the nice corrected version and its generalization. Concerning the chain of isomorphisms $H^n(G,M)\cong H^n(\hom_{\mathbb ZG}(F_\bullet,M))\cong H^n(\hom_{KG}(K\otimes_{\mathbb Z}F_\bullet,M))\cong \mathrm{Ext}^n_{KG}(K,M)$, I understand that the first is by definition, and the third is by the fact that $K\otimes_{\mathbb Z}F_\bullet$ gives a free resolution of $K$ over $KG$. But the second isomorphism is still unclear to me. Is it some kind of universal coefficient theorem? Sorry if this is an obvious question.

It’s just the universal property of extension of scalars. A homomorphism from an abelian group A to a K-module M is the same as a homomorphism $K\otimes A$ to $M$ and preserving the group action remains.

No. If $G$ is the trivial group and $q =p$ is a prime, $\operatorname{Ext}^1_G(V, W) = \operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/ p, \mathbb{Z} / p) \cong \mathbb{Z}/p$ but $H^1(G, V^\vee\otimes_\mathbb{Z} W) = 0$.
I suspect this is never true even for nontrivial groups. Consider the restriction of extensions to the trivial subgroup $\operatorname{Ext}^1_G(V, W) \to \operatorname{Ext}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}/ p, \mathbb{Z} / p) \cong \mathbb{Z}/p$. Should there be a canonical isomorphism $\operatorname{Ext}^1_G(V, W) \cong H^1(G, V^\vee\otimes_\mathbb{Z} W) = \operatorname{Ext}^1_G(\mathbb{Z}, V^\vee\otimes_\mathbb{Z} W)$, it feels strange that one group of extensions is always splitting over $\mathbb{Z}$ and the other is not.
Say $p = 2$, $G = \mathbb{Z}/2$, and $k = \mathbb{F}_2$, there is only one 1-dimensional representation we just call $k$, and hence $V^\vee\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} W \cong k$.
Back-of-the-napkin free resolutions got me $H^1(G, k) = \mathbb{Z} / 2$, while $\operatorname{Ext}^1_{G}(k, k) = \mathbb{Z}/2\oplus\mathbb{Z}/2$, so this is nontrivial counterexample.
There is no Grothendieck spectral sequence as tensoring with $V^\vee$ does not take acyclic to acylic, and for this reason it is unclear to me what we should expect the relationship between cohomology groups to be. But they are very much not isomorphic.
